# Power Bi Api dataset parameters empty

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-api

I'm trying to get a dataset parameters.

I'm using a local Excel Workbook file and upload it to PBI.

[image]

Then I try to get dataset params as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getparametersingroup)

When I make a request I don't have any params back.

[image]

Is it the right API ? I expect to get columns names as result.

Answer (score 0):

The [Datasets - Get Parameters In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/getparametersingroup) is not the right API. This API will return a list of parameters for the specified dataset from the specified workspace.

This won't return the data of the actual dataset, which is what you are looking for. Unfortunately this is not a support scenario with Power BI. Why do you need to retrieve the content of the Excel file programmatically?